# Drawer needs to be showed / hidden by children, to Redux or not to Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

```
<Drawer type='temporary'>
  <SomeContainer>
</Drawer>
```

I can either:

A.) Store state in the root App, pass the showDrawer / hideDrawer all the way down to the leaf component

B.) dispatch a showDrawer or a hideDrawer action that reduces the state in Redux

Which way makes more sense? Or is there an obvious and straight-forward way I missed?

Answer (score 2):

> Which way makes more sense? Or is there an obvious and
>   straight-forward way I missed?

No, you didn't. The react way is to be lifting up state, but there will be a time that lifting up state means passing through props deeper and deeper and this will become tedious. That's the moment you'll want to start thinking about redux. It's really a developers choice what fits best.I prefer to use redux. (obviously there are more benefits, but I think that's the most important one)

That said, there are alternatives. You can store a flag in localStorage or something and have your component maintain it.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest and cleanest way to communicate to parent element from children is to have callback function passed to children via props.

```
class someClass {
   toggleDrawer() => {
   // toggle state of parent here
   }
   render() {
      <Drawer type='temporary'>
         <SomeContainer toggleDrawer={this.toggleDrawer}>
      </Drawer>
    }
}
```

I don't prefer to use redux for just communicating between child and parent due to performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it recently: 
I imported MDC drawer like this:

```
import { drawer } from 'material-components-web/dist/material-components-web';
```

Then I've added some kind of menu icon which is going to toggle a drawer onClick

```
  <img className="menu-icon" src={menuIcon} alt="Menu Icon" />
```

I also included  `display: none;` in menu-icon default styling.
Then, in this case for my header component I wanted to show it when the window resizes

```
@media (max-width: 1023px) {
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

This gives an opportunity to do following in component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const $menuIcon = document.querySelector('.menu-icon');
    const $drawer = document.querySelector('.mdc-temporary-drawer');

    if ($drawer) {
        const drawerInstance = new drawer.MDCTemporaryDrawer(document.querySelector('.mdc-temporary-drawer'));

        if ($menuIcon) {
            $menuIcon.addEventListener('click', () => drawerInstance.open = true);
        }
    } 
}
```

Here if the menu-icon exists we attach a drawer instance to it